# Running Azure Functions Locally

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azure-storage, azure-functions

I have been developing and debugging my Azure Functions in Visual Studio 2017 for a few months with no problems but am now running into errors.

Every time I run my function app I get the following dialogue, which sometimes leads to my function trying to execute and other time it doesn't.

[image]

If the process gets passed the above issue I get the following errors which kill the execution of my function.

[image]

Has anyone else experienced these issues?
Thanks.

Comment: What version are you targeting? V1 or V2?

Comment: Those errors looks like are occurring inside your function.

Comment: These functions are definitely not occurring inside my function,  The function runs in Azure no problem and has been working until now.

Comment: Thanks Rob.  I believe it is .net2.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The prompt is to inform you that VS is downloading the function cli of latest version, you can check cli output, you may see

```
Starting Host (HostId=someId, InstanceId=someId, Version=2.0.11960.0,...)
```

The host version 2.0.11960( 2.4.0 is used by VS feed) represents VS consumes the latest version. Usually new release does have some breaking changes but this time as you mentioned it does work on Azure where the host version is 2.0.11961(this minor difference should have no influence on your code).

It seems your code operates on Azure File Share and I see error message

```
Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature
```

Storage SDK operations are transformed into REST http requests. This error message usually is sent back by Storage when it fails to authenticate our request.

If you have verified storage connection string(especially account key) is correct, check time settings of local pc. The REST request is sent with a [x-ms-date header](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authorize-with-shared-key#Subheading1) and the value is captured from your local pc, if it's 15m+ older than the standard time, we will get the authentication error.

Comment: Thanks.  I managed to get it working by using node to install the latest tools.